# Express/Client-Sessions: Can not res.redirect after starting a session, req.session.user

Tags: node.js, express, session, redirect, npm

I have created the session using the client-sessions npm.

res.header seems to work fine because the token has been generated as a part of the employer object. The problem is that the page does not redirect !

```
app.post('/employer/signIn', (req, res) => {
    var employer = new Employer({
        email: req.body.employer__sign_in_email,
        password: req.body.employer__sign_in_password
    });
    employer.save().then(() => {
        req.session.employer = employer;
        var func = employer.generateAuthToken();

        return [req.session.employer, func];
    }).then((token) => {
        res.header('x-auth', token).redirect("/employer/home/home.html");
    }).catch((e) => res.status(400).send(e));
});
```